# A function in C runs for a set of values but gives Segmentation Fault: 11 for another

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I am trying to find unique non-zero intersection between two sets. I have written a program which works for some set of arrays but gives segmentation fault for some. I have been trying to figure out why but have failed, any help will be greatly valued. The thing is the functions defined (NoRep and ComEle) are working fine but are unable to return the value to the assigned pointer in the case when Seg Fault is shown. Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>


int* ComEle(int ar_1[], int size_ar1, int ar_2[], int size_ar2);
int* NoRep(int a[], int l1);

int main ()

{
   // Case 1: Gives segmentation fault
   int A[10] = {1,1,0,2,2,0,1,1,1,0};
   int B[10] = {1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,4,0};
   int *C = ComEle(A,10,B,10); printf("check complete\n");


   // //Case 2: Does not give segmentation fault
   // int A[4] = {2,3,4,5};
   // int B[4] = {1,2,3,4};
   // int *C = ComEle(A,4,B,4); printf("check complete\n");


}


//---------------- Local Functions --------------------//

int* ComEle(int ar_1[], int size_ar1, int ar_2[], int size_ar2) {

// sort of intersection of two arrays but only for nonzero elements.

   int i=0, j=0, cnt1 = 0;
   int temp1 = size_ar1+size_ar2;
   int CE1[temp1]; for(i=0;i<temp1;i++) {CE1[i] = 0;}
   /* Size of CE1 is knowingly made big enough to accommodate repeating
      common elements which can expand the size of resultant array to
      values bigger than those for the individual arrays themselves! */

   for(i=0;i<size_ar1;i++) {
      j = 0;
      while(j<size_ar2) {
         if(ar_1[i]==ar_2[j] && ar_1[i]!=0) {
            CE1[cnt1] = ar_1[i];
            cnt1++;          
         }
         j++;
      }

   }
// Have to remove repeating elements.   

   int *CE = NoRep(CE1, cnt1);
   for(i=0;i<(CE[0]+1);i++) {printf("CE:\t%d\n", CE[i]);}
   printf("ComEle: %p\n",CE);
return(CE);
}

int* NoRep(int a[], int l1) {

   int cnt = 0, i = 0, j =0;
   int *NR; NR = (int*)calloc((l1), sizeof(int));
   //int NR[l1]; for(i=0;i<l1;i++) {NR[i] = 0;}
   for(i=0;i<l1;i++) {
      j = 0;
      while(j<i) {
         if(a[i]==a[j]) {break;}
      j++;
      }
      if(j == i) {
         cnt++;
         NR[cnt] = a[i];         
      }

   }

   NR[0] = cnt;  // First element: # of relevant elements.
   printf("NoRep: %p\n",NR);

return(NR);
}
```

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you tried using a debugger to help find the source of the segmentation fault?

Comment: @rtx13: No I unfortunately am unable to do so at this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
   int temp1 = size_ar1+size_ar2;
   int CE1[temp1]; for(i=0;i<temp1;i++) {CE1[i] = 0;}
   /* Size of CE1 is knowingly made big enough to accommodate repeating
      common elements which can expand the size of resultant array to
      values bigger than those for the individual arrays themselves! */

   for(i=0;i<size_ar1;i++) {
      j = 0;
      while(j<size_ar2) {
         if(ar_1[i]==ar_2[j] && ar_1[i]!=0) {
            CE1[cnt1] = ar_1[i];
            cnt1++;          
         }
         j++;
      }
   }
```

Here you have nested loops, i.e. a for-loop with a while-loop inside. So - in worst case - how many times can `cnt1` be incremented?

**The answer is `size_ar1 * size_ar2`**

But your code only reserve `size_ar1 + size_ar2` element for `CE1`. So you may end up writing outside the array.

You can see this very easy by printing `cnt1` inside the loop.

In other words - your `CE1` is too small. It should be:

```
   int temp1 = size_ar1*size_ar2;  // NOTICE: * instead of +
   int CE1[temp1]; for(i=0;i<temp1;i++) {CE1[i] = 0;}
```

But be careful here - if the input arrays are big, the VLA gets huge and you may run in to stack overflow. Consider dynamic memory allocation instead of an array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Your solution indeed works. If I may ask: how shall I go about dynamically allocating CE1 to overcome this situation? Like would not I have to still allocate the same memory? You mean, I can free that later in the function or something? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @user3474947 Dynamic allocation: `int* CE1 = malloc(temp1 * sizeof *CE1);` and once you don't need `CE1` anymore, do `free(CE1)`. Yes, it's the same amount of memory but your stack (where VLA goes) have a limited size. The heap (where dynamic memory goes) is much larger. So huge objects shall always be dynamic allocated. Example: `void foo() { char hugeArray[20000000]; ...}` is something you should never do!

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the accepted answer: I have been missing a break statement in the while loop in ComEle function. It was not giving me the expected value of cnt1. The following will be the correct way to do it:

```
for(i=0;i<size_ar1;i++) {
      j = 0;
      while(j<size_ar2) {
         if(ar_1[i]==ar_2[j] && ar_1[i]!=0) {
            CE1[cnt1] = ar_1[i];
            cnt1++;
            break;
         }
         j++;

      }

   }
```

This will also do away with the requirement for a bigger array or dynamic allocation as suggested (and rightly so) by @4386427